# Can a GFCI plug on the same circuit as a range cause a fault for power getting to the range plug?

Tags: stove, power

I have a standard 220v plug for an electric range. There is also a GFCI plug along the same circuit but it is tripped and I cannot get it to reset. If the GFCI plug is tripped could that cause a reduction in the current to the 220 for the range?

Comment: This sounds like a really poor circuit layout to have a 120v receptacle on the same circuit as a 240v appliance, possibly non-compliant with NEC. The 240v appliance should have a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Have you checked if an upstream circuit breaker is tripped? If the whole circuit is off the GFCI might not reset and of course, the circuit would have no power.

Comment: Can you add your country of origin to your profile, or edit your question to show where you are in the world? We will be able to better diagnose and answer your question because the electrical systems vary quite a bit country to country.

Comment: I updated my info, but for the sake of speed, I am in central Alberta, canada. My house is not a fixed unit, it is a mobile home that is about 2 years old. We bought it brand new however

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.   The 240v power to the range must go only to the range.  You can't fork off one leg of the 240 and a neutral to also serve a 120v plug.  Of any kind.  If you need a 120v plug there, you need to either run a new circuit, or add an outlet to an existing circuit.

That, however, does not explain why the GFCI is tripping.   The GFCI would not know it was applied illegally - as long as it sees 120v across its line terminals, it is happy.   The fact that it is tripping suggests to me that either it is defective or you have connected it to 240v.  Or it is working properly and you are plugging in an appliance which has a ground fault, such as a 3-light electricity tester.